# Do spam bots use cached versions of web pages?

Tags: bots, spam, honeypot

I have a site that receives a lot of spam form submissions so a week ago I set of a honey pot. I'm still getting the same amount of fake submissions so I was wondering if spam bots used the cached versions of web pages? Will the amount of spam reduce in time? I thought I'd be able to easily Google this question but no!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, yes. The bot will cache your website when it is first crawled. One of the most popular bots for this is called XRunner, XRumer and many other bots will often try to register by sending a request directly to the registration form (carrying over the session cookie). In order to populate the form, the bots will use fields names, text is then injected into the field values containing that name (this process is written into a script / used by a standard script against XenForo registration), these field names will often be standard field names such as name = "name", name = email, name=password.. etc

I hope this helps!